# Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool crash due to missing CoreText

Tags: cocoa-touch, macos, interface-builder, xcode4.2, core-text

I'm trying to build an iPhone application but each and every time (regardless of target settings), XCode returns an error during the linking stage when compiling the XIBs.

I managed to track down the problem: XCode is launching "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" but this utility immediately crashes on load with the following message:

```
Last login: Wed Jan 18 00:54:27 on ttys004
[mqudsi@iqudsi:~]$ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/Interface\ Builder\ Cocoa\ Touch\ Tool ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
  Referenced from: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool
  Reason: image not found
[1]    2338 trace trap  

[Process completed]
```

The path it's searching for, `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/`, does not exist on my machine, and according to my Time Machine backups, it never did either. I believe CoreText is an iOS-only framework, and it *shouldn't* be on my machine.

I'm using XCode 4.2.1 and I've attempted to update OS X Lion and to completely remove and reinstall XCode, to no avail.

Anyone know what's going on here? Or how I can avoid the launching of this touch tool (I don't *think* it's actually required to build?).

Comment: Exactly the same issue. This only occurred recently though and not sure what I've changed. Probably installed an incompatible library or something. Let me know if I can help in any way. _Note: Mac OS X Cocoa application builds and runs fine. Issue is iOS only._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix to my issue.  I was running Asepsis by Binary Age and forgot about the XCode incompatibility.  If you are running Asepsis then running the uninstaller found [here](https://raw.github.com/binaryage/asepsis/master/installer/uninstall.applescript) should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you. You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I installed Asepsis back when I purchased TotalFinder a year ago.

Comment: Credit goes to PhoneyDeveloper of the MacRumors forum, he's the one that reminded me of Asepsis! http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1310396